# Show message for disable product : M2

Tags: magento2, product-view, product-urls

Is there any way to show any message for disable product at product details page?

When i search product name in google, it gives product URL in search result.

When product is disable at that time it gives 404 page not found, so i want to show disable message for that disable product instead of 404 page not found.

Answer (score 0):

By default disable products does not show at fronted,its mean there is no way to display message at product detail page while it is not showing up/disabled. However you can create url rewrite for old/disable products to custom cms page to display any message about product through marketing > url rewrite

Comment: i don't want to redirect to cms page, i want to show that page instead of 404 page not found

Comment: Aright! we have two options in magento disable product and out of stock product. when we disable a product it does not appear on frontend,site search nor category listing.However if the  product set to "out of stock" than  product  will not appear frontend,site search or category listing , but still that product have working product page if shopper has the direct product url  he can browse that page , he would not able to add that product to cart due to out of stock flag with product.

Comment: For cusom message display copy
vendor/module-catalog-inventory/i18n/en_US.csv
into your theme 
app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/i18n/en_US.csv
and add your translation to it: what ever message you want to display on the page